# Using my Swift internationalisation strings with just one operator definition

Tags: generics, swift3, autocomplete, localization, operators

Throughout all the frameworks I have used in the past years I have always been displeased with the way localisation read in code. It was either overly complicated to define a "key" (as in Swing) or it felt too brittle (as in Rails). Additionally, the tooling support (especially autocomplete or the like) always left a lot to be desired.

So I set out to see how far I could achieve my goals in Swift. I roughly tried to achieve the following:

- Have compile time checked key-constants in my code instead of procedure calls with string parameters or even macros
- Be able to define new keys with minimal syntactic fuss while staying compile time safe
- Be able to fetch localisations from different `.strings` files, not just `Localizable.strings`
- Be able to call a localisable string with minimal syntactic overhead while maintaining autocompletion in Xcode
- Permit the representation of existing translation tables (which might have spaces in their keys)

Here is what I came up with (in a Playground, so I just emit the `NSLocalizedString` calls instead of actually calling it as in the code).

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

protocol Localizable {
    var key : String { get }
    func localized() -> String
}

extension Localizable {
    func localized() -> String {
        return "NSLocalizedString(\(key))"
    }
}

prefix operator §

enum Default : String, Localizable {
    case hello
    case world = "this planet"

    var key : String { get { return rawValue } }

    static prefix func §(str: Default) -> String {
        return str.localized()
    }
}

Default.hello.localized()
§.hello
§.world
```

which would work for `Localizable.strings` and extended it as follows for strings in other files:

```
protocol TabLocalizable : Localizable {
    var table: String { get }
}

extension TabLocalizable {
    func localized() -> String {
        return "NSLocalizedString(\(key), table:\(table))"
    }
}

enum WorldTable : String, TabLocalizable {
    case earth
    case proximaCentauriB = "Proxima Centauri B"

    var key : String { get { return rawValue } }
    var table : String { get { return "worldTable" } }

    static prefix func §(str: WorldTable) -> String {
        return str.localized()
    }
}

WorldTable.proximaCentauriB.localized()
§.earth
§.proximaCentauriB
```

My primary way of defining my `keys` would be `enums`, since they clearly require the least amount of syntax to define a new key. A simple

```
case newKey
```

is enough and the only thing you will need then is a corresponding definition in your `.strings` file. For existing `.strings` files where you might have spaces in your keys you will have to be a little verbose, but

```
case spacedKey = "Spaced Key"
```

is not too bad I think. Defining keys is easy enough and using the values as

```
Default.world.localized()
```

still feels less brittle than `NSLocalizedString("world“)`. However, it does not quite satisfy my definition of 'minimal fuss'. As it turns out we can further shorten the code by using prefix operators. Since these must start with a "strange" character I chose to use `§` as my operator as it does not seem to have a specific purpose in the language although it is readily available on most keyboard layouts and it alludes to "having something to do with language".

This leads to

```
§.world
```

as a localised string reference which is hard to beat on brevity. So now all my keys are compile time tested and autocompletion works wonders for finding existing keys.

However I have one little nagging point about this: In order for autocompletion to work I have to put the (almost identical) operator definition into each and every `enum` definition. This seems like a small price to pay and it probably is, but I still would like to ask if somebody knows a way to only have to define it once.

Putting

```
static prefix func §(str: Localizable) -> String {
    return str.localized()
}
```

into the definition of the `Localizable` protocol looks like a good idea at first, but

```
§.hello
```

will fail with

```
error: type 'Localizable' has no member 'hello'
```

and even the call

```
§Default.hello
```

will fail with

```
error: generic parameter 'Self' could not be inferred
```

which points me into the direction that there 'might' be a way to define `prefix func §` with a clever `Self` parameter in the right place, but I cannot see how it could be done. I hope there are still some subtleties of Swift that allow for this type of "generic operator" in some way.

If you find more genericity at some point it would be nice if you pointed this out in the comments.

Comment: Try global `prefix func § <T: Localizable>(str: T) -> String`

Comment: @user28434 This looks promising. It can at least cover for `§Default.hello`, but it will fail on `§.world` with `error: generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
§.world`. This seems a tad strange as long as there is no "real" ambiguity (at which point it would be understandable). The error is the same for all values after `.` so obviously completion will not work.